# What is this aircraft?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

[32°09'16.6"N 110°50'36.4"W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/32%C2%B009'16.6%22N+110%C2%B050'36.4%22W/@32.1545974,-110.8435192,56m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d32.1546111!4d-110.8434444), co-ordinates of the aircraft at Davis-Monthan Air Force base.

[image]
<sub>Source: Google Maps</sub>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are [Learjet 35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learjet_35)'s. In USAF service, they're called [C-21](http://www.af.mil/AboutUs/FactSheets/Display/tabid/224/Article/104522/c-21.aspx)'s.

[image]

[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/USA-Air-Force/Learjet-35A-ZR/2737725/M)

Comment: Do you know what they are used for? According the link its used for "cargo and passenger airlift", but the military has tons of other aircraft for this. Why do they need such a small one?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, I'd guess that C-21s are used mainly for moving high-ranking officers from Point A to Point B on short notice.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg -- they'd be used for VIPs, urgent military couriers, and such, as well as miscellaneous support roles (aircraft that size are commonly used as target-towing tugs or small-scale electronics platforms for range support, EW threat simulation, equipment flight test, and other such niche roles)

Comment: The info linked at theair force site mentions " In addition to providing cargo and passenger airlift, the aircraft is capable of transporting one litter or five ambulatory patients during aeromedical evacuations.
" and mentions medical staff under the crew specs. No idea if this means it's ever been used that way though.